# Item not dropping on DragTarget in flutter

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag an item on Target. if even draggable an item minor touch to the target's offset point it should be dropped to DragTarget. The issue is I have to drag more than 50% on DragTraget then and then it's dropping on target.

I tried to find distance but DragTarget is not giving distance onMove if draggable item touch to DragTarget.

Expected Result should be like if draggable touch to target as shown in image then item should be dropped but in actual scenario it's going back.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dva7J.png)

here is my code

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: false,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: List.generate(6, (index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(44.0),
              child: index == _indexOfDroppedItem
                  ? Draggable<int>(
                      data: index,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                      ),
                      childWhenDragging: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                      ),
                      onDragStarted: () {
                        _setIsDragging();
                      },
                      onDraggableCanceled: (_, __) {
                        _resetIsDragging();
                      },
                      onDragCompleted: () {
                        _resetIsDragging();
                      },
                      feedback: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                      ),
                    )
                  : DragTarget<int>(
                      builder: (
                        BuildContext context,
                        List<dynamic> accepted,
                        List<dynamic> rejected,
                      ) {
                        return Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(_isDragging
                              ? const Radius.circular(20)
                              : const Radius.circular(10)),
                        ));
                      },
                      onMove: (details) {
                        if (kDebugMode) {
                          print("Distance ${details.offset.distance}");
                          print("dx ${details.offset.dx}");
                          print("dy ${details.offset.dy}");
                        }
                      },
                      onAccept: (int data) {
                        _acceptDraggedItem(index);
                      },
                    ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please provide some code so that others can help you. See [here for how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).